# How to get nearest timezone compare to specific timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have a list/array of timezones and I want to find the nearest timezone to a specific timezone ( where my customer is )

```
$timezone = ['Pacific/Honolulu', 'America/Anchorage', 'America/Santa_Isabel', 'America/Los_Angeles'];
```

And let's say my customer is in Europe/Paris Timezone.

How can I find the nearest timezone from the $timezone array?

Looking for a solution in PHP.

Comment: Hi. The nearest timezone in the list? for Europe/Paris would it be Europe/Oslo or Europe/Podgorica? Or other ?

Comment: You'll need to define "nearest" more clearly. Perhaps "the time zone which, at the time the script runs, has the closest UTC offset"? Do you care what happens if there's a tie?

Comment: What I mean by nearest is by the difference in the number of hours or minutes, the lesser the difference is the closest one

Comment: But many zones have the same time offset. i think you should forget timezones, and just use time offsets (but in case you need to plan in advance, e.g. with summer time, but in this case your method is also not working).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates)